# Grouping components to make sub-components

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make what I think is called sub components in React though I can't find any official up to date documentation on how to do this. My issue is I would like to make a large form with different sections broken up as bootstrap cards, within a card I want an arbitrary number of rows of `input`s.

Ex)

```
Section 1
    First_Name    Last_Name
    Email_Address

Section 2
    Address
    City     State     Zip
```

The code looks something like this for Section 1:

```
<div className="MyCard floatingCard card">
  <h5 className="MyCardHeader card-header">Section 1</h5>
  <div className="MyCardBody card-body">

    {/* Row 1 */}
    <div className="row">
        
        <div className="form-group col-md-6" style={{ marginBottom: "2em" }}>
          <input />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group col-md-6" style={{ marginBottom: "2em" }}>
          <input />
        </div>

    </div>

    {/* Row 2 */}
    <div className="row">
        <div className="form-group col-md-12" style={{ marginBottom: "2em" }}>
          <input />
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The above is not very clean, and I would also need to do the same for section 2, is there a way to make this look like:

```
<FormSection header="Section1">

    <FormRow>
        <Input name="firstName" label="First Name"  />
        <Input name="lastName" label="Last Name"  />
    </FormRow>

      <FormRow>
          <Input name="email" label="Email address"  />
      </FormRow>
</FormSection>

<FormSection header="Section2">
    <FormRow>
        <Input name="email" label="Email address"  />
    </FormRow>

    <FormRow>
        <Input name="city" label="City"  />
        <Input name="state" label="State"  />
        <Input name="zip" label="Zip"  />
    </FormRow>

</FormSection>
```

Comment: Are you using React-Bootstrap? Your last snippet looks basically like standard practice. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I am using react-hook-form.   The Input component would be a styled <input> tag

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear. Even with your alternate approach you'd have to specify column widths, etc. in the markup. It wouldn't be as clean as you've shown.

Comment: FYI, Bootstrap 4 has [margin classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/) available. I'd avoid the inline styles and use them instead.